# Jquery ui version of the jquery mobile flip toggle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Is there a jquery ui version of the [jquery mobile flip toggle](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/switch)?

```
<label for="flip-a">Select slider:</label>
<select name="slider" id="flip-a" data-role="slider">
   <option value="off">Off</option>
   <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

I really like the flip switch and was going to use on my mobile site, but I'd like to keep the same look and feel on the main site as well.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery-checkbox plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-checkbox/) does this, although it is ugly as sin.